# Aiogram. Функция callback query handler, передающая значение в заданном диапазоне

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Присутствует бот в телеграм, где администраторы отвечают на вопросы пользователей.

Есть функция, генерирующая количество кнопок в зависимости от количества заданных вопросов пользователем:

```
for i in range(0,len(group_msgs)):
    btn = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(text=str(group_msgs[i]["ID"]), callback_data=str(group_msgs[i]["ID"]))
    kb.add(btn)
```

И callback query handler, который должен принимать callback_data этих кнопок.

```
dp.register_callback_query_handler(show_question,text="?????")
```

Тут необходимо создать функцию, которая будет принимать значения в заданном диапазоне, допустим от от 1 и до 99999 (ID вопросов в базе данных)